# Google Maps API - Event listener for API/JSON load?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I'm making a map that loads some area highlights via a REST API in a JSON. This JSON is quite big, so I'd like to put a loading screen on the map until the API call returns. I've tried:

```
document.getElementById('spinner').style.visibility = "visible";
map.data.loadGeoJson(mapurl);
document.getElementById('spinner').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

But apparently the loading occurs asynchronously, so this achieves nothing.

Second trial:

```
document.getElementById('spinner').style.visibility = "visible";
map.data.loadGeoJson(mapurl);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(){
        document.getElementById('spinner').style.visibility = "hidden";
})
```

This is much better, now I have a loading screen, however, `idle` gets called right after the *map* loads, but not the JSON. Is there a way I can listen to the event of the JSON file being fully loaded/API call returns?

Comment: `loadGeoJson` accepts an optional callback which will be fired once all the features are loaded, i.e, `map.data.loadGeoJson(mapurl, callback)`. So, place your callback there.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand much what they want to do, I assume that after loading the map I want to have an ajax query, to do this declare a function(init) and add to the google maps tag as callback, something like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=init" async defer></script>
```

your function:

```
function init(){
    // Load ajax
}
```

Comment: I've found the solution since (not much to do with AJAX), so I've marked my question as a duplicate.